# Align at top in tabularx

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I want to make with an equation or calculation in the left column and a description in the right column. I have trouble when the equation contains fractions.
Here is an example:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    Foo & Bar\\\hline
    $\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{5}{6}$ & \lipsum[1]
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

This looks like this:
[image]

My question is this: How do I get rid of the white space above the text in the right column? I know I could fix it with `raisebox` but I am hoping for a more general solution where the baseline of the right column is somehow fixed or ignored by the text in the left column.

I hope someone can point me en the right direction.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `\dfrac` (which does enlarge the left formula)? In displaystyle the baseline seems right.

Comment: You can use the package `array` and use a column as `m{6em}`  for the first column, but the equation is now aligned with "Lorem ipsum". It seem to me a bad idea change it.

Comment: @TeXnician In my case it has to be `dfrac` because it has to be very clear (to my students) what goes on in the formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `\raisebox` with the height and depth of the box:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\topalign[1]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{#1}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\ht0+\dp0\relax}{\usebox0}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
Foo & Bar\\\hline
\topalign{$\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{5}{6}$} & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`adjustbox` can help in such circumstances because its `valign=t` option aligns to the top of the box, rather than the baseline of first line of the box.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  Foo & Bar\\\hline
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{$\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{5}{6}$} &
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Swann, but the fractions still seems to be a little bit too high.